# R studio crashes when trying to use package Geneland

Tags: r, rstudio

I have installed package Geneland (https://github.com/gilles-guillot/Geneland) using github on my MacOS BigSur v.11.2.2 , R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15), after running it successfully in past and then deleting it.
First time, I have a huge problem with the installation, but now there was no problems with gfortran etc. that I have encountered when installing it for the first time.

Right now I am dealing with R session aborted ("R Session Aborted: R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated.") when I try to run PostProcessChain after running the MCMC analysis. R session just crushes with no error information. So the software itself run the analysis successfully, I just cannot get any output of the results.
Is there any solution to this or at least a way to find out where is the problem?

The only difference is that I think I had older version of R before.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi Lenka, welcome to SO. I hope someone encountered this problem already before and is able to help you. NeverthelessI believe this kind of problems are better suited to writing an issue to the developer of the package (https://github.com/gilles-guillot/Geneland/issues/).

Comment: Does it fail in R without RStudio? This sounds like it is not an issue with the IDE, but I might be wrong.